# How can I test my app in an iPhone 4 simulator on OS X?

Tags: ios, xcode5, ios-simulator

I am starting iOS development. I have created an application and I am using Xcode 5.0.2, and I'm running the iOS Simulator for an iPhone 5. I want to test my application in the Simulator for an iPhone 4.

Is any tool like Genymotion Emulator (for Android) to run test my application on iPhone 4?

Comment: There is a menu in the simulator where you can choose the device (screen size) you want.

Comment: You mean 3.5 inch screen or lower version of iOS?

Comment: @Thanh-Nhon NGUYEN. I mean lower version.

Comment: @JonhKevin What do you mean by lower version?

Comment: @Popeye I wanted to run my application on simulator iphone 4 not simulator iphone 5 so, I mean that simulator iphone 4 is lower version.

Comment: And what's stopping you just selecting the iPhone like `odukku`s answer?

Comment: @Popeye but I really don't understood about that picture.

Comment: Around where you have the run button you will see one of those from the dropdown list (Probably `iPhone Retina (4-inch)`) just click on that and you can change it have a read of https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH1-SW1 this document will explain all you need to know about the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the version of simulator from Xcode itself. Pls check the image for better understanding[image]

Comment: This is about device, not version then.

Comment: @Thanh-NhonNGUYEN Yes this is about changing the device not the iOS version

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible in XCode, but if you have a developer account, you can achieve this by using real device.

Change the deployment target in project properties (general tab):

[image]

Though with my Xcode 5.1.1, I can only reach the 6.0 as the lowest version.